How to Make Line Charts Smooth in ECharts.js
I’m working with a large dataset and rendering it using ECharts.js. However, the lines in the chart appear jagged and strange. I want to make the lines smooth for a better visual experience.

Here’s the current configuration of the chart:
https://gist.github.com/yulafezmesi/3b3dcea46b7b1083408c61076b003654
What can I change in the configuration to make the chart lines smoother?
thank you

There exists a sampling option which might be helpful.

hi @MatthiasMertens tried all options, but it didn't work.
